# Bluetooth for Linux Study Guide and Python3

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

The Bluetooth for Linux Study Guide:

https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/the-bluetooth-for-linux-developers-study-guide/

Does not seem to address the issue of a D-Bus library for Python3.

It appears that there is not dbus version available:
https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/

Is there a solution?

Comment: that's the beauty of open source. You can get involved yourself and drive things forward. PR's are welcome.

Comment: by the way, here is it were it goes next:
https://python-dbus-next.readthedocs.io/en/latest/